# How to print a function's return string without its body?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html document that contains 4 paragraphs.

I want to take the concatenation of all paragraph's innerHTML and put it in the paragraph with "demo" id. The problem is that it also prints the function's signature...

How can I print only the string that my function returns?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<p>The DOM is very useful.</p>
<p>This example demonstrates the <b>getElementsByTagName</b> method</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script >
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");


    function getText() {
        var text=null;
        for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            getText = getText + paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
        }
        return getText;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=getText();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I get this as a result:

> Hello World!
>
> The DOM is very useful.
>
> This example demonstrates the getElementsByTagName method
>
> function getText() { var text=null; for (var i = 0; i <
>   paragraphs.length; i++) { getText = getText + paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
>   } return getText; }Hello World!The DOM is very useful.This example
>   demonstrates the getElementsByTagName method

Comment: use a different variable name for the text inside the function

Comment: try to avoid `innerHTML`. It adds an unnecessary serialization and parsing step to your task (overhead), and if for example some other script would have added event-listener to some of the processed nodes/markup, they would have been gone now; they don't serialize. Better would be to accumulate the childNodes you want in a DocumentFragment (the accumulation prevents multiple render-steps), and to just move/append them to the target Node (`demo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your function with :

```
function getText() {
        var text="";
        for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
            text= text+ paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
        }
        return text;
    }
```

In your case, you were returning `getText` which is name of your function that's why the method is also getting appended

Comment: Explanation will help the OP understand the issue, instead of just providing answer

Comment: @Pugazh I also provided the explanation of his issue with answer

Comment: Great, this would help!

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're returning the function, not the text.

```
// Main function declaration
function getText() {

    // Setting the initial string (text) and all paragraphs (<p>)
    var text = "";
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p')

    // Loop over all paragraphs
    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
        // use the .concat() function to combine the strings (with a space behind it)
        text = text.concat(paragraphs[i].innerHTML + " ");
    }

    // Return the string in variable text as a result of the function.
    return text;
}

// Enter the string in the demo p.
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getText();
```

[Here's a codepen (working) example.](http://codepen.io/robertspier/pen/gwpKgw)

Comment: This is slightly better, but it'll still prepend "null" to the return value.

Comment: Yeah, i'll edit the answer in a second, this isn't favorable anyway.

Comment: Now it'll prepend "undefined".

Comment: I haven't finished my coffee @Juhana, thanks for correcting.
Should be fine now, updated + comments!

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the variable 'text' not getText();

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Hello World!</p>

<p>The DOM is very useful.</p>
<p>This example demonstrates the <b>getElementsByTagName</b> method</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
    var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("P");

    var text = "";

    function getText() { 
        var i; 
        for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
           text += paragraphs[i].innerHTML;
        }
        return text;
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = getText();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```